# Regex to split with multiple separators of one or several characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string with separators ' or .. WHILE KEEPING them:

```
"'TEST' .. 'TEST2' ".split(/([' ] ..)/g);
```

to get:

```
["'", "TEST", "'", "..", "'", "TEST2", "'" ]
```

but it doesn't work: do you know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[' ] ..` pattern matches a `'` or space followed with a space and any two chars other than line break chars.

You may use

```js
console.log("'TEST' .. 'TEST2' ".trim().split(/\s*('|\.{2})\s*/).filter(Boolean))
```

Here,

- `.trim()` - remove leading/trailing whitespace
- `.split(/\s*('|\.{2})\s*/)` - splits string with `'` or double dot (that are captured in a capturing group and thus are kept in the resulting array) that are enclosed in 0+ whitespaces
- `.filter(Boolean)` - removes empty items.

Comment: can't you keep my [ ] because I may have other separators like " & etc. ?

Comment: @user310291 That makes sense if you mention it in your question, else it may confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure it will work for every situations, but you can try this :

```
"'TEST' .. 'TEST2' ".replace(/(\'|\.\.)/g, ' $1 ').trim().split(/\s+/)
```

return :

```
["'", "TEST", "'", "..", "'", "TEST2", "'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting while keeping the delimiters can often be reduced to a `matchAll`. In this case, `/(?:'|\.\.|\S[^']+)/g` seems to do the job on the example. The idea is to alternate between literal single quote characters, two literal periods, or any sequence up to a single quote that starts with a non-space.

```js
const result = [..."'TEST' .. 'TEST2' ".matchAll(/(?:'|\.\.|\S[^']+)/g)].flat();
console.log(result);
```

Another idea that might be more robust even if it's not a single shot regex is to use a traditional, non-clever "stuff between delimiters" pattern like `/'([^']+)'/g`, then `flatMap` to clean up the result array to match your format.

```js
const s = "'TEST' .. 'TEST2' ";
const result = [...s.matchAll(/'([^']+)'/g)].flatMap(e =>
  ["'", e[1], "'", ".."]
).slice(0, -1);
console.log(result);
```